# Cannot find package "tests"

Tags: python, sharepoint

i imported following:

```
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from tests import test_user_credentials, test_team_site_url
```

however "tests" is not recognized (Import tests could not be resolved) it's not clear what package needs to be installed. i pip  installed:

```
pip install Office365-REST-Python-Client
```

and i thought tests would be installed too. I cannot find a package called tests so nervous to pip install tests if it causes conflict. Does anyone know what i need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can copy `tests` from here:

https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/tree/master/tests

or clone repository using Git.

You can also try:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client.git@master
```

but this will install whole repository.